# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать при какой то заданной n=x в данном коде, было сразу x результатов

Tags: python

```
import hashlib
import json
import requests
import time
import telebot
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
import schedule
```

x=n # то есть запускается 1 раз скрипт и выводится 10 различных запросов(ввиде мб for или while)

```
app_id = "dsggdsgsdg"
secret = "sdgdsgsdg"

nonce =str(time.time())
params_string = json.dumps(
    {"app_id": app_id, "nonce": nonce},
    separators=(',', ':')
)
sign_get = hashlib.md5((params_string + secret).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
url=https://google.com/
token=requests.get(f'url={app_id}&nonce={nonce}&sign={sign_get}')
# print(token.text) 
token = json.loads(token.text)
print('Наш токен', token['token'])
```

Comment: В вашем коде нет ни `n`, ни `x`. Совсем не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать. Пожалуйста, добавьте более подробное описание в ваш вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit]

Comment: @nomnoms12
Сделать такие образом, что при одном запуске будет выводиться столько разных значение(так как будет грубо говоря запускать ее несколько раз), сколько укажу(где то в коде)

Answer (score 1):

если правильно понял

```py
x = 5 # сделать 5 раз

for i in range(x):
    # здесь повторяемая логика
```

Comment: Подскажите, как это можно совместить с моим кодов. Что бы я получал сразу 5 токенов, вместо 1